# FileZilla passwords

Tags: ftp, password-management, filezilla

I have quite a few FTP sites saved in FileZilla, however I want to use different client now. How can I see the passwords saved in FileZilla so I could transfer them?

OS is Linux (Ubuntu 9.04) if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export your Site Manager entries and you'll find them in plain text.

> File > Export > Export Site Manager entries

Open up the file you've exported to and they're all there in an XML structure like the following:

```
<Server>
 <Host>ftp.example.net</Host>
 <Port>21</Port>
 <Protocol>0</Protocol>
 <Type>0</Type>
 <User>ash</User>
 <Pass>k3tc#um!</Pass>
 [...]
</Server>
```